# How to get raw data instead of vector with PromQL?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am querying for memory usage from a software's endpoint which is connected with Prometheus (monitoring system). Following is the query,

```
curl -k -s -X GET "https://192.168.6.13/metricsservice/query?query=(engine_memory_total_bytes)" -H "Authorization: Bearer 14ac2d8-9097-455e-baf5-f426f9e208b7"
```

And the result is the following

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "resultType": "vector",
    "result": [
      {
        "metric": {
          "manager": "false",
        },
        "value": [
          1611002532.041,
          "1026170880"
        ]
      },
      {
        "metric": {
          "manager": "true",
        },
        "value": [
          1611002532.041,
          "7817961472"
        ]
      },
      {
        "metric": {
          "manager": "false",
        },
        "value": [
          1611002532.041,
          "7817965568"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So the values are in vector format (notice the `"resultType": "vector"`).

How can I pull the real data instead of vector?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) filter, like in the following example:

```
curl -k -s -X GET "https://192.168.6.13/metricsservice/query?query=(engine_memory_total_bytes)" -H "Authorization: Bearer 14ac2d8-9097-455e-baf5-f426f9e208b7" | jq --raw-output '.data.result[].value[1]'
```